# Updating empirical cumulative function

Tags: r

I have the following problem:

given a stream of observations, find the number of observations that are less or equal to the currently last observation. For example, if the streaming observations are

> 8, 1, 10, 3, 9, 7, 4, 5, 6, 2

then we have the following updates

1. Observations - 8, there is 1 observation less or equal 8
2. Observations - 8, 1, there is 1 observation less or equal 1
3. Observations - 8, 1, 10, there are 3 observation less or equal 10
4. ...

As a result one would obtain such values

> 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2

The solution should be very fast as I am working with huge dataset.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I have no working solution except trivial loop and calculating number using `length(which(...))`

Comment: Are your data integers, or are they floats?  If the values belong to a (relatively) limited set of options, there may be ways using running totals or the equivalent of hash tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `for` but in the reverse direction, I don't test but I think it is faster.

```
xx <- c(8, 1, 10, 3, 9, 7, 4, 5, 6, 2)
res = vector('integer',length=length(xx))
for (i in rev(seq_along(xx))) {
  res[i] <- sum(xx[i]>=xx)
  xx <- xx[-i]
}
res
[1] 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 4 5 2
```

Comment: Yes, it is almost three times faster on my data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply`:

```
vec <- c(8, 1, 10, 3, 9, 7, 4, 5, 6, 2)

sapply(seq_along(vec), function(x) sum(vec[seq(x)] <= vec[x]))
# [1] 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 4 5 2
```

Since performence is important, you can also use `vapply`. It might be faster (untested):

```
vapply(seq_along(vec), function(x) sum(vec[seq(x)] <= vec[x]), integer(1))
# [1] 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 4 5 2
```

Comment: No actual improvement when using `vapply` over `sapply`.

Comment: Since each calculation here is independent of the others, there are two paths to follow.  You could break up the `seq_along(vec)` into several chunks and use the `parallels` package.  But I think the interesting (so to speak) approach is to recognize that you can save a lot of calculation when a value is repeated in your sequence. That is: if vec[27] is the same value as vec[13], then you only need to calculate the sum over 14:26 and add it to the previously-calculated `output[13]` .   Or maybe that's just insane :-) .  I'm going to try using the `order` function.

Comment: Actually I was experimenting with `order`, `cummax`, `ecdf` with no luck. Would be great to see simple and elegant solution using `base` functions.

Comment: I fear there is no 'slick' solution, because every element of `vec` is potentially unique, so there is no information from the calculations of elements `1:j`  that can be used to calculate the value for element `j+1` . (other than edge cases like `if(count(j)==1 & vec[j+1]<vec[j])`, which isn't much help)

Comment: Sven - just wondering if you see any way to speed up my late answer

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't leave well enough alone, so I created a kludgemonster

```
   carl<-function(vec) {
newct<-vector('integer',length=length(vec))
vlen<-length(vec)
for(j in 1:length(vec) ) {
    wins<- (which(vec[j:vlen] >= vec[j])+j-1)
    newct[wins]<-newct[wins]+1
}
}
```

It appears to work, but...

```
Rgames> set.seed(20)
Rgames> vec<-runif(2000)



 Rgames> microbenchmark(carl(vec),agstudy(vec),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
    carl(vec) 86.75314 87.55323 88.16816 88.80831 89.65117    10
 agstudy(vec) 70.26213 70.83771 71.06158 71.72247 71.93800    1
```

Still not quite as good as agstudy's code.  Maybe someone can tighten up my loop?

Comment: Carl, I don't see any possibilities to significantly improve the code. Just a minor note: You calculate `length(vec)` three times.